# Identifying Isomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, vector-space-isomorphism

[image: Q1]

I understand that the conditions for isomorphism is that

1. close under multiplication/addition
2. T(-v) = -T(v)
3. preservation of identity

However, I'm confused about number 2. I know that 1 and 3 are both isomorphic.

But in case 2, how do we determine f(-1) or the matrix indices without the function f itself? Is it necessary to determine the isomorphism.

Comment: Those conditions that you mention are about subspaces. They have nothing to do with isomorphisms.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos you are correct. My head went completely somewhere else. Thank you for catching my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An isomorphism has to be invertible by definition. Let's see than which of the three you mention it's so:

1. $T:P\rightarrow P$ defined as $T(f)=f'$: this cannot be an isomorphism because by integrating $f'$ you get $f+c$ so a family of functions. Differentiating a polynomial get's rid of the constants and you cannot retrieve them in any way by integrating.
2. $T:P_3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ defined as $T(f) = \left[\begin{matrix}f(-1)&f(0)\\f(1)&f(4)\end{matrix}\right]$: for this let's choose a base $\mathcal{B} = \{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ for $P_3$ and than evaluate the the image of the base by $T$: $$T(1) = \left[\begin{matrix}1&1\\1&1\end{matrix}\right]\\ T(x) = \left[\begin{matrix}-1&0\\1&4\end{matrix}\right] \\ T(x^2) = \left[\begin{matrix}1&0\\1&16\end{matrix}\right] \\ T(x^3) = \left[\begin{matrix}-1&0\\1&64\end{matrix}\right]
   $$
   let's choose the standard base for $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$:  $\mathcal{C} = \left\{ \left[\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&0\end{matrix}\right],\left[\begin{matrix}0&1\\0&0\end{matrix}\right] ,\left[\begin{matrix}0&0\\1&0\end{matrix}\right] ,\left[\begin{matrix}0&0\\0&1\end{matrix}\right]  \right\}$ and write down the matrix of the transformation $$A=\left[\begin{matrix}1&-1&1&-1\\1&0&0&0\\1&1&1&1\\1&4&16&64\end{matrix}\right]$$ the determinant of $A$ is positive, so the map is invertible
3. $T:D_3\rightarrow P_2$ defined as $T\left(\left[\begin{matrix}a&0&0\\0&b&0\\0&0&c\end{matrix}\right]\right) = ax^2+bx+c$: let's use this basis for $D_3$ and $P_2$ $$\mathcal{B} = \{1,x,x^2\}\;\;\;\;\;\mathcal{C} = \left\{\left[\begin{matrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{matrix}\right], \left[\begin{matrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{matrix}\right], \left[\begin{matrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right]\right\}$$ and see where $T$ maps the basis to write down the matrix of this map $$T\left(\left[\begin{matrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{matrix}\right]\right) = x^2 \\ T\left(\left[\begin{matrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{matrix}\right]\right)=x\\ T\left(\left[\begin{matrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right]\right) = 1$$ then, easily enough, the matrix representation of this map is $$A = \left[\begin{matrix}0&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\end{matrix}\right]$$ which has determinant $-1$ so it's invertible.

Comment: what allows the second case to choose a random basis? Thank you for your response. Likewise, wouldn't a determinant of -1 be non-zero, so that should be invertible?

Comment: Well they're not **random** basis. The basis I choose were all standard basis, just to simplify calculations. You could choose any other base because under the choice of a bases $$\mathbb{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})\cong Hom(\mathbb{R}^n,  \mathbb{R}^n)$$ which to put it simple, after choosing a base the matrix representation is **unique**

Comment: Yes, my bad, it's invertible

Comment: I understand now. 

Regarding the last condition, you attain determinant -1 but say its not invertible. Aren't all non-zero determinant matrices invertible?

Comment: Yes, they are! I've just corrected it

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am currently practicing for my midterm examinations, and need clarifications on these sticky problems. 

I was hoping if you can also look into answering this question here: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2859273/subspaces-in-rnxn

I do not understand this question very well. Sorry about my grammar. My english is very poor, and am from Brazil

Comment: Yes I'll answer it later

Comment: I really appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: Don't worry, we're all here to help! I'm helping you from the other side of the world ahah!