# Isomorphism Clarification and Identification

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

I understand that to claim isomorphism, algebraic properties must be preserved...so....a) closed under multiplication and closed under addition.

However, I am unsure how to apply these condition-testing properties in the context of polynomial/space based questions

For example: Which of the following is isomorphic to a subspace of R^3x4

1. P9
2. P11
3. Upper triangular matrices in R^2x3
4. R12

How can I show closed under addition/multiplication in each of these contexts?

Comment: It is a little hard to tell which spaces you mean in your enumeration, can you elaborate on that. Also, do you mean with R^3x4 the space $\mathbb{R}^{(3,4)}$ of $3$ by $4$ matrices?

Comment: Yes, that is the space. 
P9 refers to characteristic polynomial with degree 9, and p11 refers to characteristic  polynomial with degree 11

Comment: So, I assume that with characteristic polynomial with degree $9$ you mean the matrices which have a characteristic polynomial of degree $9$, i.e. all $9\times 9$ matrices?

Comment: Vector spaces are classified by their dimension. For vector spaces $V$ and $W$ there exists an injection $V \to W$ if and only if $dim(V) \leq dim(W)$. Hence for your problem you just need to figure out the dimension of each space

Comment: @leibnewtz would all of these choices be subspaces:

Comment: @leibnewtz would all of these choices be subspaces:

We have 9 <= 12
We have 11 <= 12
We have 6 <=12 -> 6 from 2X3
We have 12<=12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler way to find out if two finite dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic, as others said, is to find out what if the dimension of the vector space that you're studying. So we can state a little "theorem"

> Two finite dimensional vector spaces $V,W$ are isomorphic iff $$\dim(V)=\dim(W)$$ Here are some [references](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Dimension_Characterizes_Isomorphism).

After stating this we can easily find out which of your vector spaces is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 4}$. First of all we have that $$\dim(\mathbb{R}^{3\times 4}) = 12$$ and it's easy to see because to write down a $3$ by $4$ matrix you need  $12$ indipendent components.

Now let's see the other dimensions $$\begin{align} 
P_9 &&\rightarrow&&\dim(P_9)=9\tag1\\
P_{11} &&\rightarrow&&\dim(P_{11})=11\tag2\\
\text{upper triangular }\mathbb{R}^{2\times 3}&&\rightarrow&&\dim(\text{upper triangular }\mathbb{R}^{2\times 3})=5\tag3\\
\mathbb{R}^{12}&&\rightarrow&&\dim(\mathbb{R^{12}})=12\tag4
\end{align}$$

For the first and second one the dimension is trivial to find: a polynomial of degree less and equal to $n$ has $n$ coefficients, so the vector space is $n$-dimensional. The third one is more tricky: one would think that the dimension would be $6$ but an upper triangular $2$ by $3$ matrix is of the form $$\left(\begin{matrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\0&a_{22}&a_{23}\end{matrix}\right)$$ 
so the element $a_{21}=0$ always. The only independent components ar the $5$ left. The fifth is just $\mathbb{R}^n$ so it's dimension is $n$.

Clearly the *only* isomorphic space to $\mathbb{R}^{3\times2}$ in this list is $\mathbb{R}^{12}$. If you want to find an isomorphism, which is not requested if the only thing you want is to find if to vector spaces are isomorphic, you could use this isomorphism $$\phi:\mathbb{R}^{3\times4}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{12} \\
\left(\begin{matrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}&a_{14}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}&a_{24}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}&a_{34}\end{matrix}\right)\mapsto (a_{11},a_{12},a_{13},a_{14},a_{21},a_{22},a_{23},a_{24},a_{31},a_{32},a_{33},a_{34})$$ i.e. you take all the entries in the matrix and map them to a vector that has as components the $a_{ij}$ of the matrix.

Comment: Can you elaborate further as to why P9 and P11 are not isomorphic. I simply thought because their dimensions are smaller, they can be isomorphic

Comment: If being isomorphic means to have an isomorphism between two spaces, necessary the two spces **have** to have the same dimension. An isomorphism is a map with a one-to-one correspondence: if you have $n$ elements in a set and $m$ in another, with $m>n$, you cannot construct an isomorphism because, at most,  $n$ of the $m$ elements can be mapped from one set to another

Comment: I'm from a phone now and I cannot give you a thorough explanation! When I'll be on pc I'll give you a better answer

Comment: I see. I think I'm thinking in terms of dimensions.

For example, if I had a linear transformation T from V to R^2x2 with the Kernel{T} =0. Then I know for sure that dimension V is less than or equal to 4. Or is that the wrong assumption?

Comment: What you're saying is true but in this case the linear map you're searching is an isomorphism which let's you know that the two spaces on which it operates are isomorphic (so they have the same dimension)

Comment: Can we apply isomorphisms to orthogonality? For example, can we relate isomorphism to a kernel of an arbitrary matrix...and somehow prove that the image is orthogonal to its kernel......or if the kernel of the transpose matrix is orthogonal to the kernel of its original matrix.....or if the image of the transpose matrix is orthogonal to its kernel of the original matrix....

Comment: I don't really understand what are you trying to accomplish...In the exercise you gave us you just wanted to know if some spaces were isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 4}$ You have to understand better the notion of dimensions and isomorphism (in this case you don't need to find a isomorphism to prove that two spaces are isomorphic and it will be pretty rare that you will be asked such question) before trying to tackle this kind of problems. Now if you have any other questions, ask them as a separate post and me as well as other MSE users will be eager to answer

Answer (score 1):

Leibnewtz is right for finite dimensional vector spaces. You basically just need to count the number of degrees of freedom in your space to determine the dimension. For example, an element of $R^{(3,4)}$ contains 12 degrees of freedom, so it has dimension $12$. So it is obvious that $R^{12}$ is isomorphic  to $R^{(3,4)}$. You could also easily construct the isomorphism between these spaces, for example, by stacking the columns of an element of $R^{(3,4)}$ into a single long column vector, and check that this map preserves algebraic properties.

Comment: Is it false for infinite dimensional spaces?

Comment: would all of these choices be subspaces:

We have 9 <= 12
We have 11 <= 12
We have 6 <=12 -> 6 from 2X3
We have 12<=12