# Differential Equations Proof for Equilibrium

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, limit-cycles

[Q1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7pko.png)

I haven been told that the system of Differential Equations are continuous partial derivatives, and also there exists a solution l(t) that is a limit cycle of the system. I have to prove why this system must also retain an equilibrium solution.

I know that continuous partial implies that the functions are necessarily differentiable. Since we also know that there exists a function that is a limit cycle of the system, then there exists a point which the function revolves around. And since the system is a continuous partial derivative, then this equilibrium solution must exist.

Is this an adequate proof for the question in hand?

Thank You

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), not pictures. Regarding your question, (provided that I understand you correctly) if the two-dimensional system of ODEs is defined **inside** the periodic orbit, indeed, there exists an equilibrium inside this orbit. But this does not follow from the existence and uniqueness theorem at all, but is a (not so straightforward) consequence of the [Brouwer fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem), a highly nontrivial result in itself.

Comment: To the downvoter: as the OP wrote in [the other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2859271/identifying-isomorphisms), English is not his/her native language. Here, he/she gave his/her thoughts on the subject (and It took me less than 5 minutes to understand them).